# Focus() on dynamically created server control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating buttons dynamically using a SQL query:

```
private void createPagingButtons(DateTime firstDayofWeek, DateTime lastDayofWeek)
{
    int i = 1;
    //get query that holds all of the names for a date range
    SqlDataReader returnedQuery = getDefaultUser(firstDayofWeek, lastDayofWeek);
    while (returnedQuery.Read())
    {
        string buttonName = returnedQuery["Person"].ToString();
        string[] splitString = buttonName.Split('(');
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = buttonName;
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        btn.Text = splitString[0];
        btn.Width = Convert.ToInt32(splitString[0].Length)*9;
        btn.CssClass = "dynamicButtons";
        pagingPanel.Controls.Add(btn);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Because of this, I don't have specific names for them that are static on the ASP.NET side. On postback I would like to button.focus() the one that was clicked.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `btn_Click()`, set a page-level variable (e.g., `this.clickedButtonId`) to the ID and then in `createPagingButtons()` call `btn.Focus()` if `btn.ID==clickedButtonId`:

```
string clickedButtonId;

private void createPagingButtons(DateTime firstDayofWeek, DateTime lastDayofWeek)
{
    int i = 1;
    SqlDataReader returnedQuery = getDefaultUser(firstDayofWeek, lastDayofWeek);
    while (returnedQuery.Read())
    {
        string buttonName = returnedQuery["Person"].ToString();
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = buttonName;
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);              
        //...
        pagingPanel.Controls.Add(btn);

        if (btn.ID==this.clickedButtonId) btn.Focus();

        i++;
    }
}

private void btn_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
{
   this.clickedButtonId = ((Button) s).ID;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate?